# Are line breaks possible when programmatically composing a message in messages app?

Tags: ios, swift, message, messageui

Is it possible to have a line break in the default body of my SMS message when redirecting from my Swift iOS app?

Comment: Have you tried adding `\n` to your string?

Comment: And if you used UILabel to display,have you set its lines to 0(unlimited)?

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible to create a line break in a SMS message. It's achieved by using the escape `\n` , as noted by [@EmilioPalaez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725628/emiliopelaez). The code below demonstrates how this can be done.

```
// Create Message Controller //
let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

// Set Its Delegate //
messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

// Set Recipient(s) //
messageComposeVC.recipients = ["555-555-5555"]

// Create Body Text (Note the use of "\n") //
messageComposeVC.body = "This is your message. \nThis is your message on a new line."

// Present Message Controller //
presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

**Update**

You could alternatively remove the use of an escaped newline character (`\n`) and simply use block text:

```
// Create Message Controller //
let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

// Set Its Delegate //
messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

// Set Recipient(s) //
messageComposeVC.recipients = ["555-555-5555"]

// Create Body Text (Note the use of an opening and closing """) //
messageComposeVC.body = """
This is your message.
This is your message on a new line.
"""

// Present Message Controller //
presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

By using `"""` to indicate a block of text, we can simply format the text in a visual way.

Using this method of creating a string allows us to put items on a new line, indent, and more without using certain (not all) special escaped characters. We can simply remove the escaped newline (`\n`) here and just put the intended text on an actual new line instead.